# Stubbing request\responses for middleware tests in Express

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, middleware, sinon

I have some middleware functions in my Express app which make outgoing request to a separate server and then send the response returned back to the client.

So this kinda thing:

```
var request = require('request'),
  helpers = require('./helpers.js');

//GET
module.exports.fetch = function(req, res) {
  var options = helpers.buildAPIRequestOptions(req);
  request(options, function(err, response, body){
    res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
  });
};
```

I am looking at writing unit tests and would like to mock out and return my own responses when the outgoing requests withing these functions gets fired.

I have come across supertest and have had a go at writing a suite like so:

```
var app = require('./index.js'),
  request = require('supertest')(app),
  should = require('should');

//GET
describe('GET requests', function(){
  it('should do something', function(done){
    request
      .get('/api/schemes')
      .expect(200, done)
      .end(function(err, res){
        // console.log(res);
        // console.log(err);
        res.status.should.equal(200);
      });
  });
});
```

I think I need something like sinon here, so I could spy on a request that would hit my middleware function and return a response of my choosing. I am just struggling to understand how to add the stubbing to my test.

Can someone advise further please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[node-nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) can record requests made via the `http` module (and so, by proxy, request). These can then be queued for replaying in your test suite. The GitHub page has great documentation.

Comment: nock is what I use for mocking external web requests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it certainly looks like something of use, just got to figure out how to use with the example I shared in my OP!  :)

Comment: @mindparse throw in a `nock.recorder.rec();` before the request and you'll get the code to mock the response you got just then in your console.